# Getting all same side pairs

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, grid-deduction

The goal is to get same side pairs of the 6 tiles,

[image],

to fit into a $2\times 3$ grid, so that all touching sides match like so (excluding the red part), for example:

[image]

Comment: Are we allowed to rotate the tiles? Also, is 2x3 two wide or three wide?

Comment: You can rotate, and if you can rotate, whether it's $2\times 3$ or $3\times 2$ doesn't matter.

Comment: did you make the example up?

Comment: is the answer unique? can you flip tiles?

Comment: This is also known as tetravex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

3 solutions i found, no idea if there are others

> [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

Comment: Dang, but I gotta say: If the solution is not unique, what's the point? I feel like the puzzle suddenly has much less value since little effort is actually needed to construct such puzzles...

Answer (score 4):

I found this by hand. I don't know if this solution is unique.

> ```
>      4   2
>    1 X 5 X 5
>      2   6
>    6 X 3 X 1
>      5   2
>    1 X 1 X 3
>      4   4
> ```

I'll draw a picture of it later.

Comment: why do i even try

Comment: @JanIvan Sorry I just beat you to it. It is interesting that you found the same solution as I did. Maybe it really is unique.

Comment: Yea found second, and it is very similar honestly

Answer (score 3):

There are exactly

> 8 solutions, or if we don't count rotations, the answer is 4 solutions, or if we count $3\times 2$ table, 16 solutions.

solutions!

How did I find them?

> Programming :P

Where are the solutions?

> [image]

And?

> [image]

And??

> Source code: https://gist.github.com/DesWurstes/a62fd071c918279e6d1f0c86f37bd6aa

Comment: Rather than saying "I solved it, I'll edit my post soon with the answer", please just post the answer first time around

Comment: Only 4 if you don't count rotations.

Comment: Yes but we're allowed to rotate.

Comment: In that case there are 16, since you can also rotate 90 degrees.

Comment: Yep. It is. My fault.

Comment: This is really good.